# Reading objects in Json

Tags: json, node.js

I have a json file but I can not access a file inside the file.How can I read with Javascript?I can not access the "language" data in the following json file, how can I read?

```
 "metadata": {
  "anaconda-cloud": {},
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python [conda env:probalistic]",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "conda-env-probalistic-py"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're loading the json from a file on disk, then you should be able to achieve this via the following:

```
// Import file system module
var fs = require("fs");

// Load json data from file, via file system module
var data = fs.readFileSync("/path/to/your/file.json");

// Parse the json data to an object, and access required data
var json = JSON.parse(data);
var languageFromJson = json.metadata.kernelspec.language;

// languageFromJson contains 'python'
console.log(languageFromJson) // python
```